# Is there a way to select from three columns into one value and add a string about which columns are null, without using CASE for every combination?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have three columns: id, name and description.
I am trying to write a query to display a value from three columns based on priority so only one of the columns value needs to be displayed and the priority is description, name and id.

My problem is that if description or more are missing, a message needs to be displayed stating the first available option followed by a text with info about the columns that were null or empty.

Examples:
If description is missing, it should display: name (Description not given)
If name and description are missing, it should display: id (Name and description not given)
If code, name and description is missing, it should display: Id, name and description not given

Preferably, it should be able to handle situations when id and description are missing, or when only name is missing, and ideally also be extendable to more than three columns.

How would you go about it? I tried to use CASE statements for every combination but if extended beyond three columns, that would quickly become a problem so I wonder if there is a smarter solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: unpivot with cross apply, case, pivot back up

Answer (score 1):

You will want a `CASE` expression, but it doesn't need to be complicated:

```
coalesce(description, name, id) + 
    case when description is not null then ''
         when name is not null then ' (Description not given)'
         else ' (Name and description not given)' end
```

From here, each additional column only needs to be added to the `coalesce()` call and one more `when` line in the `case` expression:

```
coalesce(description, name, id, foo) + 
    case when description is not null then ''
         when name is not null then ' (Description not given)'
         when id is not null then ' (Name and description not given)'
         else ' (Name, description, and id not given)' end
```